# Integration testing vs e2e testing on a finished application

Tags: angular, testing, integration-testing, integration, end-to-end

What makes more sense? I am testing a finished application for a company which is already being used by its customers. The software really only displays data. Which type of testing makes most sense, end-to-end or integration testing?
EDIT: If it makes any difference, the software up to now is completely untested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer and not a QA myself, but since I don't see an answers at the moment (and am unable to comment), I'll try to give you my perspective.

I imagine there are no strict guidelines, that you always have to do either, or, maybe both. Let's say you're tasked with testing a really *finished* application - you just need to verify that everything works as it is supposed to, and report any bugs that you might find, but still if it's labeled as *finished* I'd assume that's already been done. If not, then I'd start manual testing, focusing on crucial processes. Automated E2E test would be a great help if you know that the app might be further developed in the future. Adding some integration tests might make sense but you need to know what  the app is integrating with (e.g. some other apps, some public API's, database, external systems auth system). So I doubt that you'll find an answer other than 'it depends', unless you'd be able to provide a much more detailed, technical overview of the app.